# If else statement using dropdownlist

Tags: html, vb.net, if-statement, drop-down-menu

How do I write an "if else" statement using both dropdownlist and display the result on a textBox?

This is half part code of saveButton:

```
err_no = db.ExecuteInsert("INSERT INTO EFolder (No, working, Exp, points) VALUES("'" & db.sqlstr(drplstWorking.SelectedValue),
           "'" & db.sqlstr(drplstExp.SelectedValue),
           "'" & db.sqlstr(txtpoints.Text),
           Session("CnnStr").ToString)
```

here I'm trying to write the `if else` statement

```
Protected Function Mix() As Long
    Dim working As Boolean
    Dim Exp As String

    working = drplstWorking.SelectedValue
    exp = drplstExp.SelectedValue

    If (drplstWorking.SelectedValue.text) = "Y" and (drplstExp.SelectedValue.Text) = 1
    Then
        txtpoints.Text = "5"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: does `txtworking` and `txtexp` are your `dropdownlist`, If yes do not name like that use `drplst` or similar that's the better way

Comment: btw what the problem you're facing with your code? you need to be more specific to get a good answer otherwise you cant get.just like what error(s) your getting with the code?

Comment: Yup its the dropdpwnlist. The txtworking and txtexp is retrieve from sql server database (the list is not written in the html). The page is working well but i just do not know how to write a simple "If" statement using 2 dropdownlist.

for example when i select both dropdownlist, the result auto display on txtpoints (which is the Textbox)

Comment: ok ill chnage the txtworking and txtexp to drplst

Comment: dont worry Im noob and im learning ;D

Comment: just show me how you're filling these dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if drplstWorking.selectitem.text=("Y") and drplstExp.selectitem.text=("1") then
 txtpoints.Text = "5"
```